# how can i change my windows 8.1 font, without changing the icons? if possible, is there also a way to find all of the icons and replace them?

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-registry, fonts, icons

i am writing my first question here (ever).

but i would like to focus on changing my font on windows 8.1.

i already attempted this with this tool called winaero tweaker

the tool changed the fonts, but it broke some system icons (power, down, up, etc.)

the icons became squares

how can i change the font and leave the icons?

also, i found this thing called fontastic, it is an icon font generator.

i thought it has good icons that i can use.

and my second question is: how can i change my icons on the system, from the default icons? what is the icon font used in the system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the tool changed the fonts, but it broke some system icons

This probably happened, because the icons were realized as part of the font. The new font didn't have these chars implemented, so you got the squares instead.

If you use a font that implements these symbols as chars, you will get the proper output.

It solely depends on what chars a font implements.
Some fonts do implement these symbols.

> How can i change my icons on the system, from the default icons?

You can use a font editor (or icon editor) to create the missing symbols/chars and add them to the font.
Done correctly, you can create your own symbols in a font of your choice.
(But I don't know if that's possible with "fontastic")

Comment: how can i replace the icons, then? what is the icon font used in windows 8.1? i have this tool called fontforge, i can merge my icon font with all of the montserrat fonts.

Comment: what is the icon font used in windows 8.1 then?

Comment: I do not know, but from your description, it seems that the symbols are in the same font (`.TTF` file) as the chars. There are font editors (I guess `fontforge` will do it, but there are easier ones, that will show all chars realized in a font. If you compare the original font to your chosen one, you will see if there's a difference in the amount of chars/symbols realized. Look for some Windows function called "font management" or something alike.

Comment: ill just wait. i know that the custom characters have to have a certain unicode value to appear as icons.

Comment: A quick search yielded [FontViewer](https://us.fontviewer.de/). Maybe it's of some use to you.

Comment: fontviewer? i'll try it. i will reply back in a few seconds.